# JPA I:N and 1:1 using Junction table

Tags: jpa

JPA Question: I am trying to model 1:N (Person & Address) relationship using a junction table (Person_Address).

1. Person (personId PK)
2. Address (addressId PK)
3. PersonAddress (
   personId, addressId composite PK, 
   personId FK references Person,
   addressid FK references Address)

How to map these relationships? How to load list of addresses when Person object is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a OneToMany relationship which typically does not require a join table. You just have a field on the Many side that references the One side.

However, if you really want to do what you're doing, then this should work:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

...

  @OneToMany
  @JoinTable(
    name="PersonAddress",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="personId"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="addressId")
   )
  public Set<Address> getAddresses() {...}

...
}
```

Comment: You don't need `@JoinTable` in this case - unidirectional one-to-many relationship uses a join table by default, unless `@JoinColumn` is specified on it.

Comment: People choose to have a join table (rather than FK in the Address table) for their own reasons ... e.g existing schema, or wanting to allow the Address to be used by more than one Person, so not right to say "typically does not require a join table".

Comment: Using a join table is a pretty common pattern where 'ownership' is not exclusive. Example: User has zero-or-many Role(s). Role can stand on its own with no exclusive owner - there may be many User entitites that have the same Role, hence the need for the join table.