# JPA One to Many using JoinTable Error

Tags: jpa

I am trying to model 1:N (Person & Address) relationship using a junction table (Person_Address).

1.Person (personId PK)

2.Address (addressId PK)

3.PersonAddress ( 
    personId, addressId composite PK, 
    personId FK references Person, 
    addressid FK references Address
  )

```
@Entity 
public class Person {  

@OneToMany   
@JoinTable(
    name="PersonAddress", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="personId"),     
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="addressId")    
)   

public Set<Address> getAddresses() {...}  ... 
}
```

I encounter following error. Not able to find any solution.

**Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.realestate.details.Address, at table: Person, for columns:**

[org.hibernate.mapping.Column(address)] at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:269) at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:253) at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:185) at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:440) at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:192) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1108) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1293)

Comment: is that not the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520723/jpa-in-and-11-using-junction-table ?? you should have stayed there

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you don't have `@Column private Address address` in your `Person` entity
2. Make sure `Address` is mapped as `@javax.persistence.Entity`